# How can I return an ArrayList from my AsyncTask?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask

I have an AsynkTask method on my MainActivity that it's the following:

```
class chargeCars extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, ArrayList<Car>> {
        protected void onPreExecute(){
        }
        protected ArrayList<Car> doInBackground(Void... params) {

            ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

            cars.add(new Car(1,"Car1");
            cars.add(new Car(2,"Car2");
            cars.add(new Car(3,"Car3");

            return cars;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(){
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Car> c){

        }
    }
```

where `Car` it's an object that I have declared in another `Class` and which constructor it's:

```
public Car(int idCar, String name)
{
    this.idCar = idCar;
    this.name = name;
}
```

and I know that `return cars;` returns the `ArrayList` named `cars` to the method `onPostExecute` but I tried to retrieve this `ArrayList` from there and I couldn't because it always said to me that `onPostExecute` method have to be `Void`.

I have also another `ArrayList` declared in my `MainActivity` class:

```
ArrayList<Car> totalCars = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

so what I tried it's to clone `cars` ArrayList into my `totalCars` ArrayList  in my `onPostExecute` method but it gives me an error in which it says that:

> 'clone()' has protected access in 'java.lang.Object'

Here it's the code trying to clone my ArrayList:

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Car> c)
{
    for(Car cr: c)
    {
        totalCars.add(cr.clone());
    }
}
```

So I also tried to add my values directly to my `totalCars` ArrayList on my `doInBackground` method:

```
totalCars.add(new Car(1,"Car1");
totalCars.add(new Car(2,"Car2");
totalCars.add(new Car(3,"Car3");
```

but when I execute my `AsyncTask` method:

```
new chargeCars().execute();
```

the size of my `totalCars` ArrayList it's equals to 0.

What should I do? I'm totally block and I searched in SO for an answer but I couldn't find anything that helps to me.

**EDIT:** My `Car` Class it's:

```
public class Car {

    private int idCar;
    private String name;

    public Car(){};

    public Car(int idCar, String name)
    {
        this.idCar = idCar;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setIdCar(int idCar)
    {
         this.idCar = idCar;
    }

    public int getIdCar()
    {
        return idCar;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:** I put some logs to see what exactly does my program and I got strange results:

As `Clairvoyant` said, I use both of his methods but any of them works. What could I saw? Well, I saw that in the `onPostExecute` method the ArrayList contains values in both of the methods. Here there is no problem.

The problem it's that when I execute the AsyncTask in the method `onCreate` of my `MainActivity` class, my ArrayList `totalCars` doesn't have any value inside, but in the method `onPostExecute` of my AsyncTask it has all the values that I put inside the ArrayList.

What could be the problem?

**EDIT 3:** I also tried with:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new chargeCars().execute();
    Log.d("Size onCreate: ", "" + cars.size()); //It returns me a 0 -->Incorrect
   }

   class chargeCars extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {
        protected void onPreExecute(){
        }

        protected ArrayList<Car> doInBackground(Void... params) {

            cars.add(new Car(1,"Car1");
            cars.add(new Car(2,"Car2");
            cars.add(new Car(3,"Car3");

            Log.d("Size: ", "" + cars.size()); //It gives me the size equals to 3 -->Correct 
            return true;

        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(){
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(boolean c){

        }
    }
}
```

But still doesn't work. I also tried to make a `ProgressDialog` to be secure that my AsyncTask it's finished when I try to use my `Log` in my `onCreate` method but it also gives me an error (I have another question in SO about it but I don't know if it's a good practice in SO to make directly reference from another question so I don't post it here).

Am I doing something wrong? Why in my `doInBackground` it gives me the correct `size` of the `ArrayList` and in my `onCreate` method not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just declare the "ArrayList<Car> cars" outside your asynTask, and then add your cars without returning anything.

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin I have my ArrayList `totalCars` outside my AsyncTask and when I don't return anything and add the objects directly to it, it also doesn't work.

Comment: Have you debug your code???

Comment: @Clairvoyant I put some logs after executing my AsyncTask to see what it gives to me.

Comment: @Clairvoyant I edited my question with the results that I saw with your methods. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong? Why in my doInBackground it gives me the
>   correct size of the ArrayList and in my onCreate method not?

Because the execution is asynchronous and the `UI Thread` doesn't way the end of the execution of your `AsyncTask` to continue its execution flow. To get the results back, when your `AsyncTask` finishes its execution, without blocking the `UI Thread`, you could use a delegate/lister.

Let's declare an interface on the top of your Activity, and let't it implement this interface (you'll need to implement the methods). When `onCarsCompleted` is invoked you'll be able to print the correct size of your `ArrayList`

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnCarsListener {
      public interface OnCarsListener {
          void onCarsCompleted(ArrayList<Car> cars);
          void onCarsError(String error);
      }

      // the other code

      public void onCarsCompleted(ArrayList<Car> cars) {
             Log.d("Size: ", "" + cars.size()); 
      }

      public void onCarsError(String error) {

      }  

}
```

now we add a constructor to your `AsyncTask`, which takes as parameter an object of type `OnCarsListener`, and we keep a member reference to the object in the scope of `chargeCars`, and `onPostExecute` we communicate back to the `Activity` the results of your computation:

```
class chargeCars extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, ArrayList<Car>> {

    private final OnCarsListener mListener;
    ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

    public chargeCars(OnCarsListener listener) {
         mListener = listener;
    } 

    protected void onPreExecute(){
    }

    protected ArrayList<Car> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        cars.add(new Car(1,"Car1");
        cars.add(new Car(2,"Car2");
        cars.add(new Car(3,"Car3");

        Log.d("Size: ", "" + cars.size()); //It gives me the size equals to 3 -->Correct 
        return cars;

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(){
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Car> cars){
         if (mListener != null) {
              mListener.onCarsCompleted(cars);
         } 
    }


}
```

And of course, you need to instantiate the AsyncTask like

`new chargeCars(this).execute();`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80801/discussion-on-answer-by-blackbelt-how-can-i-return-an-arraylist-from-my-asynctas).

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1:**
Don't use clone just use object to add:

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Car> c)
{
       super.onPostExecute();
    for(Car cr: c)
    {
        totalCars.add(cr);
    }
       //Code for further execution
}
```

**Method 2:**
Make a method which will be called by onPostExceute() after it has got ArrayList

```
 protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Car> c)
    {
     super.onPostExecute();
       setValues(c);
    }

private void setValues(ArrayList<Car> c){
      for(Car cr: c)
        {
            totalCars.add(cr);
        }
 //Code for further execution
}
```

Comment: I tried with your first method and it doesn't work. If I put `super.onPostExecute();` it gives to me an error that says: `'onPostExecute(java.util.ArrayList<com.example.user.project.Car>)' in 'android.os.AsyncTask' cannot be applied to '()'`

Comment: If I quit it, I don't have any solve to my problem. I also have 2 doubts: why you use `super.onPostExecute()` and what do you mean with `//Code for further execution`? Now I'm going to try with your second method. Thank you!

Comment: Set ArrayList as parameter in super.onPostExecute(c);

Comment: code for further execution is nothing if you want to put any code for execution after setting arraylist you can do that

Comment: I put the super.onPostExecute like you said to me and the first method also gives me the size of my ArrayList equals to 0.

Comment: Your adding data in it passing values in constructor of car.

Comment: Your second method also doesn't return anything. Further, with your second method the rest of my programm doesn't work. I will edit my question now.

Comment: i have checked your making a dummy project and your async class woring fine and giving me ArrayList.

Comment: If your fetching data from webservice and showing here then debug and check whether you are getting data in `doInBackground()` method or not

Comment: Yes, I just simplified my code because the data of my webservices are coming ok to my doInBackground method.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves your problem otherwise your question remain unaswered

Comment: Yes I will do but by the moment I couldn't solve my problem. I don't know why it doesn't returns me the data :S (I prove your both methods)