# I am trying to show data using api . but data is not showing in custom listView . list is empty

Tags: java, android

I am trying to show data in custom listView using API 
there is no error but data is not shown in custom list .i made separate 
class for asyncTask ,Adapters and model.
code of asyncTask is

```
public class CourseOutlinesTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    Context context;
    private ArrayList<CourseModel> postList = new ArrayList<CourseModel>();
    private ListView listView;
    private View root;
    TrainerCourseAdapter adapter;
    String json_string;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            return buffer.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
            try {
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
        //close process dialog
        if (this.dialog != null) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
        //parse json
        try {
            JSONObject jsonParse = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray query = jsonParse.getJSONArray("courses");
            for (int i = 0; i < query.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonParser = query.getJSONObject(i);
                    CourseModel post = new CourseModel();
                    post.setId(jsonParser.getInt("id"));
                    post.setTitle(jsonParser.getString("title"));
                    post.setStatus(jsonParser.getString("status"));
                    post.setDescription(jsonParser.getString("description"));
                    System.out.println(post.getStatus()+"asdadasdad");
                    System.out.println(post);
                    postList.add(post);
                    TrainerCourseAdapter adapter = new TrainerCourseAdapter(context,postList);
        }catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
        }
            // Parsing json
                    post.setDescription(obj.getString("description"));

                    // ****Handle CreationDate-Object
                      // Genre is json array
            }
        } else {
            MyAppUtil.getToast(getApplicationContext(), message);
        }*/
    }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

code of my adapter class is

```
public class TrainerCourseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private  List list;
    private Context context;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    String [] cName;
    String [] cDetail;
    String [] created;
    String [] cStatus;
    TextView c_name,c_detail,c_date,c_status;
    ArrayList<CourseModel> itemList;
    Context mcontext;
    public TrainerCourseAdapter(Context context,List list) {
        mcontext = context;
        itemList = (ArrayList<CourseModel>) list;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }


    public void setItemList(ArrayList<CourseModel> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView c_name;
        TextView c_detail;
        TextView c_date ;
        Button c_status;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Holder holder = new Holder();
        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_courses_list, viewGroup,false);
         this.c_name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_courseName);
        this.c_detail = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_courseDetail);
        this.c_date = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_courseDate);
        this.c_status = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_courseStatus);
 System.out.println("Mudassir Don");

        final CourseModel data = itemList.get(i);
        this.c_name.setText(data.getTitle());
        this.c_detail.setText(data.getDescription());
        this.c_status.setText(data.getStatus());
        this.c_date.setText(data.getId());
        System.out.println(c_date);
        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+ cName[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

code of activity is

```
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_course_outlines);
        CourseOutlinesTask task = new CourseOutlinesTask();
        task.execute("http://mantis.vu.edu.pk/bridging_the_gap/public/viewCourseOutlines");
        mylist = task.viewResult();
  listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.course_listView);
        listView.setAdapter(new TrainerCourseAdapter(CourseOutlinesActivity.this,mylist ) {
        });
```

Comment: can you please set your adapter after for loop on your on postExecute Method

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign your custom Adapter to listView.

```
yourListView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

In your case, inside `onPostExecute` method of `CourseOutlinesTask` you should write it.

```
TrainerCourseAdapter adapter = new TrainerCourseAdapter(context,postList);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.course_listView);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: in asyncTask is not activity there i cannot call activity or listview in courseoutlinesTask

Comment: then you should implement an interface in your activity and trigger it from AsyncTask to return postList. then initialize adapter in your activity and assign to listview. for more info about get data from AsyncTask reffer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731121/how-can-i-return-an-arraylist-from-my-asynctask

Comment: i define method in courseoutlinesTask that return arrAylist having data. and call that method in the activity and get result and assign that result to the set adapter

Comment: i updated my question kindly see my code . list is empty till now

Comment: check whether your list is empty or not.

Comment: list is empty till now

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a interface and get response in your activity and set adapter to list view
like.

```
TrainerCourseAdapter adapter = new TrainerCourseAdapter(context,postList);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.course_listView);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use callBack interface to get itemArraylist data to your activity class.
After getting itemlist data in activity class you can set adapter to listview.

```
TrainerCourseAdapter adapter = new TrainerCourseAdapter(context, postList);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.course_listView);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

// You can create interface in your  CourseOutlinesClass with two method onSuccess() and onFailure() and in onPostExecute() send arraylist data using this interface to activity , then set adapter to fill data in listview.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_course_outlines);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.course_listView);
        new CourseOutlinesTask().execute("http://mantis.vu.edu.pk/bridging_the_gap/public/viewCourseOutlines");
}
```

and in postExecute of your AsyncTask setAdapter to listView

```
TrainerCourseAdapter adapter = new TrainerCourseAdapter(context,postList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```