# Load Recyclerview in a Thread when Activity starts

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, java-threads

I have a complex Recyclerview Adapter with two viewtypes. One for directories and the other one for documents. I make a few Database requests in the Adapter and I load a Bitmap(resized) into the document viewtype.

The directory viewtype loads really fast but the document viewtype needs some time to load. I tried to set the Adapter in a Thread. But this influences the ui Thread and Animations are laggy and also sometimes the activity starts only after the the full Recyclerview is shown.

Comment: You can use asynctask for this .

Comment: But how I get the values into the async Task und the Adapter back to the activity?

Comment: In onPostExecute you can get your values and set your adapter. See this question for implementation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731121/how-can-i-return-an-arraylist-from-my-asynctask

Comment: Okay, thank you. But why are asynctask better than Threads?

Comment: AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows performing background operations and publishing results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers. An asynchronous task is defined by a computation that runs on a background thread and whose result is published on the UI thread.

Hence it's a perfect choice for your scenario.

Comment: I hope it will work. Thank you very much for this explanation, it seems very logical.

Comment: It doesn't work. Same bugs as before. The swipeToRefresh circle is still laggy and sometimes the activity starts not until everything is loaded