# Returning ArrayList from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to get urls of songs from a server. I want to get all urls in an arraylist which can be shown in a recycler view in next activity. URLs are correctly received when I try to see them using Toast or log. But when I try to get them as a return result of AsyncTask it shows size = 0 for the arraylist returned. I have followed the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731121/how-can-i-return-an-arraylist-from-my-asynctask) specially by [Blackbelt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501696/blackbelt). But that proved to be of no use. Comments are disabled on that answer. So, here I am posting my question with the modified code. Here is the code I have written.

```
    interface OnFetchUrlsListener
    {
        public void onUrlsFetched(ArrayList<String> arrayList);
        public void onUrlsError(String error);
    }

     public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFetchUrlsListener{

    @Override
    public void onUrlsFetched(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "result size : "+arrayList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUrlsError(String error) {

    }

    private static RequestQueue mQueue;
    public static ArrayList<String> songsArray ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        songsArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        String uri = Uri.parse("https://dee9c999.ngrok.io/audio/data/WebsiteSourceCode/api/all_songs.php/?allsongs=allsongs").toString();
        new FetchSongs(this).execute(uri);

    }

    private class FetchSongs extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<String>> {
        private OnFetchUrlsListener mListener;
        public FetchSongs(OnFetchUrlsListener listener){
            mListener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
            //some heavy processing resulting in a Data String
            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, params[0], null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    songsArray.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                                }

                            }
                            catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.d("JSON Parse", String.valueOf(e));
                            }

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "Load error!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            mQueue.add(request);
            return songsArray;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {

            if(mListener!=null)
            {
                mListener.onUrlsFetched(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Edit]

```
 private ArrayList<String> startHeavyProcessing(String uri) {
        final ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, uri, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                result.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                                Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, jsonArray.getString(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            songs_fetched = true;

                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            songs_fetched = false;
                            Log.d("JSON Parse", String.valueOf(e));
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "Load error!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        mQueue.add(request);
        return result;
    }
```

Now, when I try to print result of the function startHeavyProcessing() it is returning an arraylist of size 0 but inside the function it is getting the songs urls perfectly fine.

Comment: since you are using volley for api calls, so you don't need asynctask for your code

Comment: you are messing it up actually. If you are using interface then I can't see where you are getting the list in your mainActivity class. I would rather suggest you to get your list in onPostExecute method directly and use it in your main class. As you should know that onPostExecute() runs on UI thread so no harm in there.

Comment: @Umair I did that way also.. but of no use.

Comment: @HimanshuSingh can you tell me that are you getting data in your `result` in `onPostExecute()` ?

Comment: mListener may be null

Comment: I am getting list of urls for song

Comment: @VivekMishra I tried this without AsyncTask but problem still persists. I am posting the edited code. Can you please suggest something.

Comment: I can't see any edits

Comment: @VivekMishra Can you see it now?

Comment: problem with your edited code is that now you have created a local as well as final arraylist so you won't be able to get that value outside that method

Comment: can you show the response json?

Comment: @Athira {
 "status": 200,
 "status_message": "song found",
 "data": ["https:\/\/dee9c999.ngrok.io\/audio\/data\/WebsiteSourceCode\/Shabd\/Aaradhna\/Bol.mp3", "https:\/\/dee9c999.ngrok.io\/audio\/data\/WebsiteSourceCode\/Shabd\/Aaradhna\/KiyenRijhayanTokheKiyenParchaya.mp3", "https:\/\/dee9c999.ngrok.io\/audio\/data\/WebsiteSourceCode\/Shabd\/Aaradhna\/MereSatguruPyareDa.mp3", "https:\/\/dee9c999.ngrok.io\/audio\/data\/WebsiteSourceCode\/Shabd\/Aaradhna\/NaleAlakhJeBedoTaarMuhinjo.mp3", "https:\/\/dee9c999.ngrok.io\/audio\/data\/WebsiteSourceCode\/Shabd\/Aaradhna\/OMuhinjaSatgurDev.mp3"]
}

Comment: @VivekMishra It's not the case. I had tried with static global variable also. But result is still the same.. size is 0.

Comment: give ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(); globally, declare and initialise globally, dont give final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved Your problem on a different way ...

1. as usual define this interface

   ```
   public interface OnFetchUrlsListener {
       void onUrlsFetched(ArrayList<String> arrayList);
       void onUrlsError(String error);
   }
   ```
2. write down a class, say, VolleyCall where volley get request will happen & result/response will be returned using listener

   ```
   public class VolleyCall {
       private String TAG = VolleyCall.class.getSimpleName();
       private String mUrl;
       private OnFetchUrlsListener mOnFetchUrlsListener;
       private ArrayList<String> mSongs;
       private RequestQueue mQueue;

       public VolleyCall(Context context, String url, OnFetchUrlsListener onFetchUrlsListener) {
           mSongs = new ArrayList<>();
           mUrl = url;
           mOnFetchUrlsListener = onFetchUrlsListener;

           mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
       }

       public void parse() {
           JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, mUrl, null,
               new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                       try {
                           Log.e(TAG, "_log : onResponse : response : " + response.toString());
                           JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

                           for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                               mSongs.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                           }

                           mOnFetchUrlsListener.onUrlsFetched(mSongs);

                       } catch (JSONException e) {
                           Log.e(TAG, "_log : onResponse : JSONException : " + e.getMessage());
                       }

                   }
               }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               Log.e(TAG, "_log : onErrorResponse : error : " + error.getMessage());
               mOnFetchUrlsListener.onUrlsError(error.getMessage());
           }
       });

       mQueue.add(request);
       Log.e(TAG, "_log : songsArray_size : " + mSongs.size());
       }
   }
   ```
3. modify your main activity

   ```
   public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFetchUrlsListener {

       private String TAG = SplashScreen.class.getSimpleName();

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           String url = "https://dee9c999.ngrok.io/audio/data/WebsiteSourceCode/api/all_songs.php/?allsongs=allsongs";
           VolleyCall call = new VolleyCall(SplashScreen.this, url, SplashScreen.this);
           call.parse();
       }

       @Override
       public void onUrlsFetched(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
           Log.e(TAG, "_log : onUrlsFetched : is_arrayList_null : " + (arrayList == null));
           if (arrayList != null) {
               Log.e(TAG, "_log : onUrlsFetched : arrayList_size : " + arrayList.size());
           }

           String file_names = "";
           for (String s : arrayList) {
               file_names = file_names.concat(s + "\n");
           }

          TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.text);
          tv.setText(file_names);
       }

       @Override
       public void onUrlsError(String error) {
           Log.e(TAG, "_log : onUrlsError : " + error);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Is the placement of mOnFetchUrlsListener.onUrlsFetched(mSongs) the reason for it solving the problem? Thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you dont need to return arraylist if you use this, at the end of function arraylist will have all the values

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        private void startHeavyProcessing(String uri) {

            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, uri, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    result.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                                }

                            }
                            catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();

                                Log.d("JSON Parse", String.valueOf(e));
                            }

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();

                }
            });
            mQueue.add(request);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying out.. but this does not solve my problem.